# json_encode fails because of Unknown charactar

Tags: php

I have this array :

```
[responses] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [date] => 2021-07-09 15:16:53
                                    [text] => [Resume session��%
1 Yes
2 No, CANCEL, SEND]
                                )

                        )
```

[text] is taken from USSD response and it shows `Resume session?` on phone but inside the array it is `Resume session��%`. That's where `json_encode` fails.

How to fix that !?

Comment: This is probably a Unicode issue.  When you use `json_encode`, specify the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag

Comment: @Martin didn't work . It is an invalid character can I delete it somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old but I have (the/to) answer.

```
/** @var array $array the array from question above */
$encoded_array = json_encode($array ,JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
```

**Note** : This solution is PHP 7.2 and up .. It removes the invalid character.